# how to build an Access query that contains every date in a calendar range?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table `activities` of activity entries, e.g.:

```
ID | Date       | Activity | Participant
---+------------+----------+
1  | 11/30/2011 | Skiing   | Alice
2  | 11/29/2011 | Diving   | Gary
3  | 10/15/2011 | Running  | Therese
```

and I'd like to query, for a given date range, which days had an activity and which ones didn't have anything, for every participant, e.g., for 11/29-11/30,

```
Date  |  Activity | Participant
------+-----------+------------
11/29 |           | Alice
11/30 | Skiing    | Alice
11/29 | Diving    | Gary 
11/30 |           | Gary
11/29 |           | Therese
11/30 |           | Therese
```

My current plan is to make a table `allDates` of all the dates in the year, take a Cartesian product query `cartDateParticipant`:

`select date,participant from allDates,(select distinct participant from activities) as participants`

and left join that query against `activities`:

```
select a.date, c.activity, c.participant from allDates a
left join
cartDateParticipant c
on
a.date=c.date
and
a.participant=c.participant
```

which will work, but that means I have to keep a table of dates for any possible date range entered by the user.  Is there any way to generate a sequence of dates on the fly in Access without having to store it as a table?  Or is there a better way to write this query?

EDIT: The client finally relented and decided that the blank rows were unnecessary, so I just wrote it as a standard query.

Comment: Why not keep a table of dates for any possible date? You'll only create this table once and it won't have that many rows. Only about 36K rows for a hundred years.

Comment: What's the reason to have the blank dates/user.  Absense of data is data.  If there's no user w/ that date then there's no activity for the user on that date.  Why create data?

Comment: @ypercube: yours is the answer i.e. why generate data on the fly when you can put it in a table and join to it?

Comment: @xQbert: note the Information Principle: all information in the database must be cast explicitly in terms of values in relations and in no other way. Your assertion "If there's no user w/ that date then there's no activity for the user on that date" may not be true: could be that it is not known whether there was activity.

Comment: @xQbert: that's a client requirement and I'm not in a position to push back on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll venture an answer since nobody else has.  Creating a table of dates is not perhaps particularly cool or clever.  However, it is simple to understand, and therefore straightforward to implement and to maintain.  I would stick with that method, and say, "no, there's no better way to write the query" using MS Access.

Comment: I disagree: creating a table of dates **is** cool and clever, +1 for venturing this as an answer ;)

Comment: +1 I've written several accounting programs that include a local YrMos table.  It has fields for the Year, Month, MonthStartDate, MonthEndDate, and NumOfDays.  Same concept.  I see your situation as just an expanded use case.  And once you get past thinking you're missing something clever (and maybe there is something more **clever**, but it probably won't be more **performant**) you will come around to the sentiment I share with @onedaywhen:  *creating a table of dates **is** cool and clever*

Comment: @onedaywhen point taken; "cool and clever" doesn't express my idea very well.  The idea has two parts: first, it seems that most people -- myself included -- have some sort of feeling that there should be a more concise or inventive way of achieving this.  Second, in my experience, attempting a more inventive solution generally adds obscurity and confusion.

Comment: @mwolfe02 I agree with you, but I still have the lingering feeling that storing a table like this is storing data that should be calculated.  For the same reason, I am uneasy about storing a table with integers from 1 to x (but I've certainly done it in the past).  In other words, it would be nice if we had table-valued functions that could be defined like C# iterator blocks.  But we don't!